# SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have used `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` in a Stored procedure. It seems the use of the command is hitting the performance.Can it be re-written in some other way ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcName          

AS          
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 

SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.field1 = T1.field1
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T3.field1 = T2.field2
```

Comment: Please explain how you have come to this conclusion.

Comment: do you need to read dirty data?

Comment: Can you quantify how it's "hitting performance"?

Comment: Generally speaking, `READ UNCOMMITTED` is the fastest of the isolation levels. If the query is slow, perhaps it's better to look at indexes than to mess with isolation levels.